# unable to access my free salesforce developer org

Tags: developer-edition, developer-org

I have a free salesforce developer org with a "my Domain" on it. since i forgot the password i try to reset the password, it send the line to my email. however when click that email to reset the password it takes me to the same page asking for my email again and it keeps doing that until it locks on my for requesting to rest the password so many times. any help would be appreciated at this point.

thanks,

Comment: Try on different browsers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this issue many times and only work around I have done is to change browsers .

This seems some bug and will bring to SFDC notice .